# save tif 32 bit images by using imwrite

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to save my images as tif 32 bits but I got this error:

```
Cannot write uint32 data to a TIFF file
```

This is my code:

```matlab
for k=1:10

    Id{k} = waverec2(t_C,L,'sym8');
    filename= ['C:\Path \Id_number_' num2str(k) '.tif'];
    Id{k}=uint32(Id{k});
    imwrite(Id{k},filename);

end
```

I need to save my images as tif 32 bits. Any idea?

#### Edit using the method from Ashish (see below)

```
for k=1:10

        Id{k} = waverec2(t_C,L,'sym8');
        filename= ['C:\Path \Id_number_' num2str(k) '.tif'];
        t = Tiff('filename','a')
    Id{k}=uint32(Id{k});
    t.write(Id{k});
end
```

but under Matlab I got this error :

```
Error using tifflib
Unable to retrieve ImageLength.

    Error in Tiff/getTag (line 784)
                        tagValue = tifflib('getField',obj.FileID,Tiff.TagID.(tagId));

    Error in Tiff/writeAllStrips (line 1660)
                h = obj.getTag('ImageLength');

    Error in Tiff/write (line 1228)
                    obj.writeAllStrips(varargin{:});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the TIFF format does support `uint32`, Matlab does not. Accepted intput classes are double, single, uint8, uint16, or logical.

If you losing precision is acceptable to you, you can convert it to `uint16` (use `im2uint16`). If it is not, you can convert it to `double` with `im2double`. Note that `im2double` is not the same as `double (your_uint16_image)` so be careful with it.

If none of those options are acceptable, you might need to write your own mex code using libtiff or use Octave (which will require GraphicsMagick built with quantum depth 32).

**EDIT:** apparently there is also a new TIFF class (see answer below) which gives a direct interface to it.

Comment: Thank you I've never write a mex code using octave or but at least I know that tiff 32 it's impossible under Matlab

Comment: @Ahmed you misunderstood me. I said either write a mex function using libtiff (that's Matlab), or use Octave since it's a lot like Matlab but supports writing and reading of uint32. I did not say to write mex in Matlab.

Comment: ups! The end of the previous comment should had been "mex in Octave".

Answer (score 7):

It is possible with MATLAB:

```
%
% Start with:
% http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-images.html#br_c_iz-1

data = uint32(magic(10));


%% -------------------------------------
%  Modify these variables to reuse this section: (enclosed by ----s)
%     - outputFileName  (filename in your question)
%     - data            (Id{k} in your question)
%


outputFileName = 'myfile.tif';
% This is a direct interface to libtiff
t = Tiff(outputFileName,'w');


% Setup tags
% Lots of info here:
% http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiffclass.html
tagstruct.ImageLength     = size(data,1);
tagstruct.ImageWidth      = size(data,2);
tagstruct.Photometric     = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack;
tagstruct.BitsPerSample   = 32;
tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = 1;
tagstruct.RowsPerStrip    = 16;
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky;
tagstruct.Software        = 'MATLAB';
t.setTag(tagstruct)


t.write(data);
t.close();

%% -------------------------------------

%%
d = imread('myfile.tif');
disp(class(d));
assert(isequal(d,data))
```

Comment: +1 Works! You might use something like `data = uint32(rand(100)*2^32-1);` as better example data.

Comment: Nice! I've never used `Tiff` to directly interface with libtiff.

Comment: Mr.Ashish based on the code you've mentioned my code should be like I wrote above 'I updated my code see it ' but it still not working I got this error under matlab:Error using tifflib

Comment: Ahmed, your current edits in the question do not reflect the tagstruct setup and the call to t.setTag. Please try running the code in my answer and then modify it to suite your need.

Comment: Ashish I'm trying to execute step by step your code but I'm stuck at the second line  Error using tifflib
Unable to open TIFF file "myfile.tif". !!!!!! should I integrated by myself 'Tifflib'?I understand it like this, knowing that I'm using Matlab R2012a if yes I've found this http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/ but I'm confused which one I choose?:/

Comment: Ahmed, please post full error messages. Based on your explanation, I would guess that MATLAB is in a directory where you dont have write permission. And no, you need not integrate 'Tifflib', everything you need for this is part of your MATLAB installation.

Comment: Ashish,In my case I've 37 images So if I want to write each image after my treatment I should creat 37 t files right? or t file can contains all of them, knowing that I need each out image for doing further operations?

Comment: for the sake of clarity,I've 37 noisy images and after I denoised them I want to reread them under ImageJ my problem is even may file can contain my 37 data I want to write them seperatly to do my further treatments please can you help me?

Comment: Edited the code to hopefully help you get started with reusing this snippet. ('t' is a variable, not a file). If you need to work frequently with Tiff files, I would strongly encourage you to spend time reading the links in the code. It is a lot of information, but it would save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: sorry yes I meant myfile not t :p t = Tiff('myfile.tif','w'); I read the links but what I want if there is a possibly to create more than file for me I need to create 37 to write my denoised images for example t = Tiff(myfile{k} num2str(k)'w'); like this I know it's not working 'too many arguments' just an example