# how we save multiple images by using imwrite

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

can anyone help me to save my resulted images by using imwrite

```
source = 'C:\Y\';
im_number=5; 
for i=1:5 
 image{i}=im2double(imread([source,'Carbon_', num2str(i)],'tif'));  
 image{i}=double(image{i});
 B{i}= Sftfun(image{i});
 B{i}=uint32(B{i});
 imwrite(B{i},[source,'face_', num2str(i)],'tif');
end
```

Comment: please explain more of what goes wrong, what error you get, etc.

Comment: We are not voluntary coder for you and this site is not working in that way. You have to share your reason by explaining your problem better and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are casting your image to `uint32`.  If you are trying to save your image as a `TIF` file, you can only save it as 8-bit or 16-bit.  Consulting the MATLAB documentation, you can only save with these two bit depths.  32-bit depths are **not** supported.

Consult the MATLAB documentation for more details: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

As such, either cast the image as 8-bit or 16-bit (through `im2uint8` or `im2uint16`), or normalize your image so that it goes from `[0,1]` (through `im2double`).

I also have some comments about your code that do need fixing for readability:

1. Do not save your images to a cell array called `image`.  MATLAB has a built-in command called `image` which takes in a matrix and displays it to the screen for you as an image.  Bear in mind this is not the same as `imshow`.  By doing this assignment, you will shadow over the actual `image` command, and so any scripts that rely on this function will result in an error.
2. `im_number` seems to be an unused variable.  I'm not sure what its purpose is, but I'd say it's safe to remove this statement as well.
3. Get rid of the following statement as you are already converting the image to a `double` type in the previous line:

```
    image{i} = double(image{i});
```

## Aside

It seems that you have asked a similar question here: [save tif 32 bit images by using imwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635851/save-tif-32-bit-images-by-using-imwrite)

This question has already been resolved in that you are not able to save 32-bit images using `imwrite`.   However, someone in this thread has posted a workaround for you to use in MATLAB.  Try using that instead of `imwrite`.

Comment: +1 for elaborate answer to such an effortless question.

Comment: @Tae-SungShin: Thanks! :) nice seeing you again